# imagemagick convert command equivalent for iphone

Tags: iphone, imagemagick

I have no experience with imageMagick, it is a very powerfull library.

One question.
How can i convert the command line example that uses command line "Convert" command to the iphone version ?

I mean, i do not know what command to use instead of convert command

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick isn't installed by default on iPhones. It appears that someone has ported the project though: http://www.cloudgoessocial.net/2010/05/01/latest-imagemagick/

You'll probably need to use the [Magick Wand](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php) C interface to talk to the library from your program.

Comment: Yes, i installed the library.
what i have to do is:

# Reduces the number of colors in the filtered image
# Converts the original image to grayscale
# (Optionally) applies a median filter to the grayscale image
# Applies a gradient edge detector to the grayscale image
# Thresholds the edge image to binary
# Composites the edge image with the color reduced image

Can you help

Comment: I'm not an ImageMagick expert; I recommend reading the Magick Wand documentation that I linked to.